# Explanation for IOException

Tags: java, ioexception

I am new to Java and I want to know when an `IOException` occurs and what is it actually.  I also came across a point that whenever we use `BufferedReader` class to read input from console the code should be kept within `try` block and we should have a `catch` block that handles the `IOException` why is that so.  Can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you seriously searched this thing on Google?

Comment: _"Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html

Comment: Also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: @rohit yes i have searched. but i couldn get the concept behind the BufferedReader class.

Comment: @darsha. How about the documentation itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IOException is part of the interface. Errors usally occur when a file is not present, the disk is full, you are missing reading or writing privledges or you have network connectivity issues.

Depending on the implementation it might as well throw no errors at all even though its still declared in the interface.

Comment: Broadly speaking, whenever you interact your code through some I/O, you need to handle IOException.

Comment: but why don't we handle ioexception when we use Scanner class to read input from console